# Why doesn't super. call the superclass method in this code?

Tags: java, polymorphism

When I execute this code, it only returns "Eating" instead of "Studying" AND "Eating." Can anyone explain it?

```
public class Student {
    public String getFood() {
        return "Pizza";
    }
    public String getInfo(){
        return "Studying";
    }
}

public class GradStudent extends Student {
    public String getFood(){
        return "Taco";
    }
    public String getInfo(){
        super.getInfo();
        return "Eating";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student s = new GradStudent();
        System.out.println(s.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're doing nothing with the return value from `super.getInfo()`

Comment: I see, I thought return works like print or println, my bad.

Comment: It's a common mistake for beginners. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing) for an explanation (it's for python, but the concept is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getInfo()` method of the `Student` is getting invoked, but currently you are not using the result.

If, in the `GradStudent` class, you want to return a String that combines the result of the `Student.getInfo` method with the specific value from `GradStudent` you could do something like this:

```java
public class GradStudent extends Student {
    public String getFood(){
        return "Taco";
    }
    public String getInfo(){
        String studentInfo = super.getInfo();
        return studentInfo + " Eating";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student s = new GradStudent();
        System.out.println(s.getInfo());
    }
}
```